# the menu bar (the top bar) turns dark and hard to recognise

Tags: unity, menu

After I installed the KDE on my Ubuntu and chaged the theme of KDE, I found that my Unity desktop's menu bar's font's color turns dark and very hard to recognize, someone to help? I don't know how to screen shot the Menu bar

Comment: Can you take a picture from the screen with a camera?  Use a 15% perpendicular angle, do not use flash and turn off the lights to reduce glare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall KDE related things.

Then delete folders `gtk-2.0` and `gtk-3.0` inside `~/.config`:

```
~/.config/gtk-2.0
~/.config/gtk-3.0
```

Then to reset Unity run:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

Comment: The OP does not say he wants do remove KDE.

Comment: This is a procedure intended to solve the problem. This procedure involves removing KDE (and involves other actions also). I don't know if it will work and I hope other answers get posted that let the OP keep KDE, but since *keeping KDE is not stated as a requirement in the question*, this really is an answer. @user2001926 But can you explain specifically what you mean by "Uninstall kde related things"? That seems like the only ambiguous part of this answer. Do you just mean to uninstall whatever package was explicitly installed to get KDE? Or something else?